# Property does not exist - Collection

Tags: php, collections

I have a problem with a collection.
When I do

```
echo ($homeTeam)
```

I get this result [{"Hometeam":3}]

But I want only 3 back.

Then I did this.

```
echo($homeTeam->Hometeam)
```

But then I get back error Property Home does not exist...

How to do this in a correct way?

Comment: I think the object is inside an array : try this `$homeTeam[0]->Hometeam`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input `[{"Hometeam":3}]` looks like json. First need to decode it:

```
$obj = json_decode($homeTeam);
```

Then to understand structure of data -- print it:

```
print_r($obj);

// output:
// Array
// (
//     [0] => stdClass Object
//         (
//             [Hometeam] => 3
//         )
// 
// )
```

It is array of stdClass. So you can access to property `Hometeam` this way:

```
echo $obj[0]->Hometeam;
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".